# Using input element to change the title's font color when the button is clicked

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am practicing Angular and I want to change the font color of a variable named **title** but I can't get my head around it.

See the **tools.component.ts** below:

```
  [...]
  title: string = 'Add note';
  titleColor: string = 'red';
  [...]
  setBackground() {this.title.fontcolor(this.titleColor)}
```

So I thought that, if the button written in HTML is clicked, it calls the `setBackground()` method and the title's color will change. The **tools.component.html** looks like this:

```
<p>Title is {{title}}</p>
<input type="button" value="Set title color" ng-click="setBackground()"/>
```

Needless to say, this did not work.

Therefore, what should I do instead, such that when I press the input element button, the {{title}} variable's color changes?

**EDIT**:
Right, it didn't take long until I realized how to do it. Please also refer to this edit before answering.

So in the HTML, I wrote the paragraph containing the title like this:

```
<p [style.color]='titleColor'>{{title}}</p>
<button (click)="setBackground()">Set</button>
```

And the method in the **.ts** now changed to:

```
setBackground() { this.titleColor = 'blue';}
```

And, of course, it works now. However, I want the button to be an  element, so how can I achieve this with it? I tried like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Set title color" ng-click="setBackground()"/>
```

But it didnt work.

Comment: `title` is not the title element, it's just a string. Where are you using `titleColor`?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the string that is declared in the .ts. Take a look at the edit, though, as I figured how to properly use `titleColor`.

Comment: Well, with your edit this is a completely different question. Your original problem was solved. Where are you getting `ng-click` from? Are you looking at AngularJS docs and trying to use them for an Angular project? Can you expand on what you mean by "I want the button to be an element"? Buttons are elements.

Comment: What do you mean you want the button to be an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing Angular with AngularJS. `ng-click` isn't going to bind to anything in Angular. You need to bind to the button's `click` event:

```
<input type="button" value="Set title color" (click)="setBackground()"/>
```

In addition, this isn't going to work:

```
// Won't work because this.title is a string...
this.title.fontcolor
```

And finally, how are you even trying to use `titleColor`? You need to bind the color of your item in the DOM to that, and then set `titleColor` instead of `title.fontColor`:

```
this.titleColor = 'blue';
...
<p [style.color]='titleColor'>{{title}}</p>
```

[Here's a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vpmacc?file=src/app/app.component.html) on stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

make the titleColor variable as follows

```
titleColor = 'red';

setBackground() {
   this.titleColor = 'blue';
}
```